# How do I call a function included in another file? PHP

Tags: php

I couldn't  find an answer to this question elsewhere, I was hoping someone here might know. I've spent 9 hours straight trying to get this to work, I've been searching non-stop.

I have three PHP files. The third file contains my PHP functions to check for existing users and add users to the database

user.inc.php

```
<?php
//checks if given username exists in database

function user_exists($user){
    $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($user);
    $sql= "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = '{$user}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    if ($result == 1){
    return true;
    }
    else {
    return false;   
    }

}

function email_exists($email){
    $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($email);
    $sql="SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `user_email` = '{$email}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

//  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($total);
    if ($result == 1){
    return true;
    }
    else {
    return false;   
    }
}


//checks if given username/password is valid
function valid_credentials($user,$pass){
    $user = mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlentities($user));
    $pass = sha1($pass);
    $sql= "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = '{$user}'AND `user_password` ='{$pass}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if ($result == 1){
    return true;
    }
    else {
    return false;   
    }
}


//adds a user to the database
function add_user($user,$pass,$email){
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO`users` (`user_name`,`user_password`,`user_email`) VALUES ('a','b','c')");
    $user = mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlentities($user));
    $pass = sha1($_REQUEST[$pass]); 
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO`users` (`user_name`,`user_password`,`user_email`) VALUES ('{$user}','{$pass}','{email}')");
}



?>
```

The second PHP file starts the connection to the database and includes the previous file at the bottom.

init.inc.php

```
<?php 

session_start();

$exceptions = array('registerPage','login');

$page = substr(end(explode('/',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])), 0, -4);

if (in_array($page, $exceptions)=== false){
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])=== false ){
        header('Location: login.php');
        die();
    }
}

$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','yingyujiaocheng');
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `users` (`user_name`,`user_password`) VALUES ('user','pass')");

$path = dirname(__FILE__);

include("{$path}/inc/user.inc.php");
?>
```

The third PHP file includes the second file at the top and also has HTML and forms. When the form on the 3rd page is filled out and submitted, it sends the information to the top of the 3rd page to the PHP script. This is processed for errors which calls functions from the first files. The database works, I have done MYSQLI commands from every place, the only thing not working is the call from the 3rd PHP file to the first PHP file. The functions user_exists, email_exists and add_user to not call correctly.

Here is the third file:

registerPage.php

```
 <?php error_reporting(E_ALL);  

  include('core/init.inc.php');

  $errors = array();

  if(isset($_POST['username'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['email'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

     if (empty($username)){ 
         $errors[] = 'The username cannot be empty.';
     }

     if (empty($password)){
         $errors[] = 'The password cannot be empty.';    
     }

     if (empty($email)){
         $errors[] = 'The email field cannot be empty.';     
     }  

     if (user_exists($username)){       
         $errors[] = 'The username is already taken';       
     }

     if (email_exists($email)){
         $errors[] = 'The email already taken';         
     }



    if (empty($errors)){    

         add_user($username,$password,$email);
        //$_SESSION['username'] = htmlentities($username);

        //header('Location: protected.php');
        // die();
     }

  }

  ?>

  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>

  <link href="ext/Styles/styleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="header" align="centre">

  <img src="ext/Images/Logo.png" width="150" height="80" style="float:left;" />
  <h2 class="headerFontClickedSmall" style="float: right; margin-top:36px; margin-right: 60px">  </h2>
  <h2 class="headerFontUnclickedSmall" style="float: right; margin-top:36px; margin-right: 10px"> / </h2>
  <h2 class="headerFontUnclickedSmall" style="float: right; margin-top:36px; margin-right: 10px">  </h2>
  <h2 class="cornerBox1" style="float: right; margin-top:20px; margin-right: 50px">  </h2>

  </div>

  <div class="content">

  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <?php echo "Username is :" . $username . "<br>";
echo "Password is :" . $password;
?>
  <br />
  <h1 class="contentHeader" style="">  </h1> 

  <div>
      <?php 
          if (empty($errors) === false){
  ?>
  <ul>
      <?php

          foreach ($errors as $error){
            echo "<li>{$error}</li>";
         }
          ?>
      </ul>
         <?php
         }
      ?>
  </div>

  <form action="registerPage.php" method="POST">
  <h1 class="contentRegisterText" style=""> : <input class="inputbox" style="margin-left:30px" type="text"  
                                                         name = "username" id="username"/> </h1>
  <br />

  <h1 class="contentRegisterText" style=""> : <input class="inputbox" style="margin-left:30px" type="text" 
                                                         name = "email" id="email"/> </h1>
  <br />

  <h1 class="contentRegisterText" style="">: <input class="inputbox" style="margin-left:30px" type="password" 
                                                         name = "password" id="password"/> </h1>

  <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

  <input style="margin-left:30px" type="submit"  value = "" id="Register"/> </form>
  </div>

  <div class="footer" align="center" >
      <div class="floating-box" style="margin-top:40px" >
          <dl>
              <dt><h1 class="footerTitle">社交媒体</h1></dt>
              <br />
              <dd><a href="http://www.huya.com/lucio">
  <img src="ext/Images/HuyaLogo.png" alt=" " width="42" height="42" outline="none">
  </a> 
                  <img src="ext/Images/weixinLogo.png" width="40" height="40" style="margin-left:3;"/><img src="ext/Images/logo-qq.png" width="40" height="40" /></dd>          

          </dl>
      </div>

      <div class="floatingboxFooter1" style="margin-top:40px">
          <dl>      
              <dt><h1 class="footerTitle"></h1> </dt>
              <br />
              <dd><h1 class="footerSmall">:</h1></dd>
              <dd><h1 class="footerSmall">Weixin:  </h1></dd>
              <dd><h1 class="footerSmall">QQ:      </h1></dd>
          </dl>
      </div>
      <div class="floating-box" style="margin-top:64px">
          <dl>      
              <br />
              <dd><h1 class="footerSmall">bangzhu@yingyujiaocheng.com</h1></dd>
              <dd><h1 class="footerSmall">yingyujiaocheng</h1></dd>
              <dd><h1 class="footerSmall">yingyujiaocheng</h1></dd>
          </dl>
      </div>

  <div class="floatingboxFooter1" style="margin-top:40px">
          <dl>      
              <dt><h1 class="footerTitle"></h1> </dt>
              <br />
              <dd><h1 class="footerSmall"></h1></dd>
              <dd><h1 class="footerSmall"></h1></dd>
              <dd><h1 class="footerSmall"></h1></dd>
          </dl>



  </div> 

  </body>
  </html>
```

Thank you for looking, any help is appreciated,

Cheers

Lucio

Comment: for one thing `mysqli_real_escape_string()` requires a db connection for it. check that. Plus, you have a variable scope issue.  These are my findings (so far) at a quick glance. check for errors against your query.

Comment: What exactly do you mean: "... do not call correctly"? Are you getting some error message that you didn't post here?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL)` only works for logs; check them. Otherwise, display them `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: There are no errors to do with the call to those functions. When I say "do not call correctly" I mean they do not call the functions at all. I put an Echo before the call and inside the function. Only the echo before the call is printed. I've checked the queries and everything else, the problem is calling the functions themselves.

Comment: It seems that includes in includes need to be careful of the filepath, so if this is a factor read up on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920438/php-include-file-that-has-includes

Comment: Your references to includes should always be absolute - using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/address/file.php"`  (or similar) so that paths don't get lost in multiple inclusions.

Comment: Copied from below:The path to that seems to be working. I tried : include("broken/inc/user.inc.php"); (which broke upon sending the form) But : include("C:/wamp/www/YingYuJiaoCheng.com/core/inc/user.inc.php"); include("core/inc/user.inc.php"); both worked upon submitting the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to debug the `$path` variable, I think the problem is in the path you included in this line.

`include("{$path}/inc/user.inc.php");`
Or try to insert `global $con` on top of every function inside user.inc.php like so:

`function user_exists($user) {
    global $con;
    // rest of the code...
}`

Comment: If the path of the includes is an issue, then this answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9012782/3536236

Comment: The path to that seems to be working. I tried : include("broken/inc/user.inc.php"); (which broke upon sending the form)

But : include("C:/wamp/www/YingYuJiaoCheng.com/core/inc/user.inc.php");
include("core/inc/user.inc.php"); both worked upon submitting the form

Comment: Put `die();` in the user.in.php file and retry, if the page is showing the form then the problem is certainly in the include statement

Comment: Not sure where to put the die();. I put it at the start of  user.inc.php before the first function. The website is a white screen upon running.

Comment: Hmm, That means your include is working correctly,  try to create a dummy function (inside the user.inc.php) that echo somenthing, and call it through a submition script, if the method is called then the problem is around the mysql queries

Comment: Both using the form to submit, and calling dummy_function(); from the start of the script in registerPage.php do not print an output.The mysqli queries do work however from registerPage.php and outside the functions in user.inc.php      mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO`users` (`user_name`,`user_password`,`user_email`) VALUES ('c','o','m')");

Comment: Then the problem is certainly at this line ` include('core/init.inc.php');` in the registerPage.php

Comment: I changed it to the full path and still the same problem :(. If it wasn't working, then the database wouldn't connect, because the init.inc.php has the database connection in it, and within that file the connection to user.inc.php which successfully adds to the database outside of the functions :(.

Comment: Thd last idea in my head is to get rid of the enclosing php tags from the firt two files

Comment: Haha, this is the last one, put `global $con;` at the top of every function in user.inc.php file

Comment: that one worked :) But I'm not sure where to go from that haha. Should I just leave it? It's probably considered 'bad practice'

Comment: No, it's not a bad practice, its an official way to let the function know about the $con variable

Comment: @babay I would dispute that it's not bad practise, it's not advisable to set globals in this way, but to be honest, the whole global issue should be sidestepped with the Object orientated approach, but that would involve a complete site restructuring which is obviously beyond the scope of this question/answer. Using `global` should be avoided, but it does solve this specific issue .

Comment: @Martin It the person whose posted this question has taken the OOP Approach in considération, then we can talk to several solutions to solve a such problem, like creating a separate class that handles the db connection and queries and then insert it via what is known as dependency injection in whatever function he want, but unfortunately this was not the case in this quetion